# Is it good practice to add a "request ID" parameter on every api request?

Tags: logging, request

In the context of a javascript isomorphic application, I'm considering adding a unique RequestId parameter on every request of the client to the server.

This would allow logging to parse by RequestId to trace the request as it is processed in the application.

Should such an ID be added on the client or on the server upon receiving the request?

Comment: The question does not belong here, but anyway - the answer is yes

Comment: where does it belong? should I add the id parameter on the client, or on the server upon receiving the request?